# Structs and struct array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how structs work. I create a `Student * ptr` and set values in my array in `function()`.
Will the changes be persistent since I use a pointer? If I create a new function, and check `if (s->info[0].age == 10)`, it will still be 10, correct?

```
#define MAX_SIZE 10
static Student * ptr = NULL;
typedef struct {
    uint32 age;
    uint32 gradeLevel;
} Info;

typedef struct {
    Info info[MAX_SIZE];   // this array is created on the stack right?
                           // so I do not need to allocate memory
} Student;

void function()
{
    Student * s = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    ptr = s;
    s->info[0].age = 10;
}
```

Comment: The memory will persist, but the pointer to it won't exist past the end of the function. So you'll have no way to access the memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap might give you a first read about the various types of memory in a C program. Sometimes reading a bit helps ;)

Comment: With the static ptr, I will be able to access the memory, correct?

Comment: @skmiley1static pointer doesn't mean, the location where it is pointing will also remain persistent.

Comment: this comment: `this array is created on the stack right?` is wrong.  This statement: `Student * s = malloc(sizeof(Student));` allocates the array from the heap.

Comment: This is actually OK, sort of. The global 'ptr' is set to point at your malloced struct and so the struct is accessible via 'ptr' after 'function()' returns.  It is, however, still a horrible way of returning a function result.  You should return the pointer as a 'real' function result or use a double-pointer argument.  Your code is not reentrant, and so also not thread-safe.

Comment: The 'static' only defines scope - it's not really necessary here.

Comment: This question and the comments (and maybe answers) will teach you mostly about pointers, which is very useful and good for avoiding many traps. If however your intention is to learn about structs ("I am trying to understand how structs work"), then I recommend to play with **only** structs and leave the much more complex topic of pointers out.

Comment: @MartinJames the `static` *also* defines linkage, so it does something here.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, your question doesn't have anything to do with `struct`s. Also, forget about *stack* and *heap* for a moment -- C doesn't know these concepts, they are just *used* by many *implementations* of C.

What you need to know/learn about is the *scope*, *storage duration* and maybe *linkage* of objects in C:

- **scope:** The *scope* of an identifier defines the area in which this identifier can be accessed to refer to the object it represents. It is always either the area enclosed by the nearest pair of braces (`{ }`) or the *entire source file* when the identifier is declared outside any braces (called *file scope*). Example:

  ```
  int a; // a has file scope

  int main(void)
  {
      int b; // the scope of this variable is the main function
      if (1)
      {
          int c; // this variable can only be referred to inside the if block
          c = 1; // valid
      }
      b = c; // INVALID, c is not "in scope" here
  }
  ```
- **storage duration:** The storage duration of an object determines how long the object lives. You should know about the following storage durations:

  - **static:** An object with *static storage duration* lives for the entire execution time of the program. A variable declared in *file scope* has *static storage duration* **by default**. You can explicitly give a variable *static storage duration* using the `static` *storage class*:

    ```
    int a; // static storage duration by default
    int func(void)
    {
        static int b; // explicit static storage duration.
        // If you enter this function multiple times, you will get the SAME variable
    }
    ```
  - **automatic:** An object with *automatic storage duration* lives exactly as long as execution is inside of its *scope* (or in a function called from this scope). This is the **default** for all variables **not** in *file scope*. Therefore, the following code is **wrong**:

    ```
    int *func(void)
    {
        int a = 5; // automatic storage duration
        return &a; // ERROR
    }
    ```

    once this function exits, `a` doesn't exist any more because execution left its *scope*. So the pointer this function returns doesn't point to a valid object.

    There's a *storage class specifier* for this storage duration, `auto`, but since you can't give *automatic storage duration* to a *file scoped* variable anyways (it would be meaningless), this keyword is arguably *useless*. In a function, you could write `auto int a;` which is exactly the same as `int a;` because it's the default here.
  - **dynamic:** An object *allocated* with `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` has *dynamic storage duration*. This means it lives *exactly until* you explicitly `free()` it. The allocation functions return you a *pointer* to an object with *dynamic storage duration*. This is what your example program uses, so **returning this pointer from a function is fine**. The object will live as long as you like, once you don't need it any more, you have to call `free()`.

---

With this information, you should understand what your code does. I left out *thread storage duration* and anything about *linkage* because it doesn't directly relate to your question and you can learn about these things later.

Your `struct` just defines a *structured data type*, this is a type that consists of multiple member objects. It doesn't change anything about the rules above. In your example, your whole `struct`, including the array of another `struct`, is **one** allocated object with *dynamic storage duration*.

---

Getting back to the first paragraph, a typical C *implementation* will place objects with *static storage duration* in a *bss segment* (allocated on program startup), objects with *automatic storage duration* on the *stack* (growing dynamically with each function call) and objects with *dynamic storage duration* in the *heap*. But this is just the *typical* implementation and C would also work on platforms that don't even provide these concepts.